# useFetch hook based on use cases causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I tried to create a useFetch hook based on diferent use-case and I can't deal with this task.

First of all, I have a service, a repository and then call a use-case:

```
const userService = new UserServiceImpl(apiConfig);
const uploadImageService = new AmplifyS3Service();
const userRepository = new UserRepositoryImpl(
   userService,
   uploadImageService
);
const getUserUseCase = new GetUserUseCaseImpl(userRepository);
```

I would like to optimize every tasks, fetch data from **getUserUseCase** because returns a Promise, put on the state and map trough data. My whole application is based on use-cases

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();
getUserUseCase.getUser().then(setUser)
```

I tried to create a useFetch hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useFetch = (useCase: Promise<any>) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    data: null,
    loading: true,
    error: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    useCase.then((data) => {
      setState({
        data,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
      });
    });
  }, [useCase]);

  return state;
};
```

and then I call it passing a use-case by argument...

```
const userInfo = getUserUseCase.getUser();
const { data, loading } = useFetch(userInfo);
```

after this point, I get a infinite loop, and I don't know which part I'm doing wrong.
Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that everytime this runs, a new promise object is returned:

```
const userInfo = getUserUseCase.getUser();
```

Which you then pass to `useFetch`:

```
const { data, loading } = useFetch(userInfo);
```

Which is then used as an effect dependency:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    useCase.then((data) => {
      setState({
        data,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
      });
    });
  }, [useCase]);
```

Which means that each render that effect is getting triggered, because on each render the effect dependencies have changed.

---

I'm guessing then, that you do not want this to run on every render:

```
const userInfo = getUserUseCase.getUser();
```

Which means you should memoize it so it always has the same value each render and only runs once.

```
const userInfo = useMemo(() => getUserUseCase.getUser());
```

Now `userInfo` has *stable identity* and can safely be used as an effect depedency.

Comment: Thanks Alex! your approach is very good but I think that solution is more complex than that because I need to type the outcoming data because typescript tells that data is null... and I need to think from other perspective. Thanks again!